# Can you send the value from @Model.Sum from a View to Controller? ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I summed up the values in my view and I wanted to send the total back to my controller but I'm not sure if there is a way to do that.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Rest.Models.ShoppingCartItem>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.item)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Menuitem.ItemName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Menuitem.Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<h1>
    @Model.Sum(i => i.Menuitem.Price)
</h1>
```

Is there a way I can send the value I computed back to my controller?

Also, this is my first time using HTML - how do I make the font and formatting look nice? Can someone point me towards some good references?

Thanks!

Comment: You could wrap it in a form and 'submit' it back.

Comment: Use bootstrap for styling to start with. It has many predefined CSS classes to apply styles on HTML elements.

Comment: `Is there a way I can send the value I computed back to my controller?` Can try to use a hidden field to store that value and send it back to server.

Comment: You do sum on the data in your viewmodel. I believe, your model got data from controller, so you should be able to use the same logic to gather data and do sum on serverside. Why would you send it back from here? User can modify the value in the browser inspect tools and hack the total!

Comment: @Pirate lol im not that advanced yet, I didn't know the user could do that! That's a good point, ill try to figure out how to sum the values in my database first.

Comment: @Pirate is bootstrap something I have to install as a Nugget package to use?

Comment: @BlairWaldorf when you return data to the view and do sum in view, you should be able to gather data in controller with same logic. Instead of returning it to the view, just calculate the total on server and use that. More secure and reliable way. Regarding bootstrap, Google it online, there will be many articles on it. You will have add CSS and js files. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com)